# Visitation statistics

Tags: discussion, statistics

I was wondering what would be the response to Stack Overflow (Exchange really) collecting and displaying statistics on user visitation?

For example, by country, the amount of questions/answers, most used tags from region, amount of reviews, votes etc...

This doesn't seem very intrusive to me and has research value (social sciences mainly I guess), plus is interesting.

If this seems OK, can it be implemented in the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 7):

If you have 25k reputation, you get access to [site analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics). This might contain some of the information you're looking for. Other than that, you can explore the information available to you via [quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com#/trafficCard).

Comment: Quantcast is cool, didn't know about it. I was thinking about something more fleshy though, slicing through preferred topics etc. I'm not sure analytics would have that either, at least as they are described.