# Is there any way to know when Stack Overflow users are being the most active?

Tags: discussion, statistics

As I was opening my Stack Overflow page on this Monday morning of my time zone, I was imagining some people being tired and not really ready to answer questions after the week-end, while some others were already posting a lot of questions. That is at least what my top questions page confirmed me, with a lot of new questions with a low amount of views and no answers compared to some other hours.

While I was thinking about this, I started asking myself when the Stack Overflow community is being the most active during the day, especially knowing that there is SO users all other the world. By active, I am mainly thinking about the days and hours when people are asking and answering the most questions, more than when people are looking for answers and up/downvoting around.

I guess users with more than 25K reputation may have access to such an information thanks to the associated [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics), but is there any way to get such an information? I am asking this out of pure curiosity, but that can also be interesting for people who are not fast enough to answer questions compared to really active users, and who would like to do their first points during less active hours maybe.

Comment: Those stats only go to the day level... There was however a recent blog post you may be interested in at https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/04/19/programming-languages-used-late-night/ (and there's a link in that post so you can do a breakdown by specific tags: https://dgrtwo.shinyapps.io/tag-traffic-hour/)

Comment: @JonClements Oh, I thought there may be some way to aggregate all these data over several weeks and to get a global tendency. But the blog post you shared is really interesting and is answering a good part of what I was looking for.

Comment: I've re-tagged to include the `statistics` tag - you might want to peruse other questions in that tag, eg: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338037/visitation-statistics is listed which also provides a link to quantcast... Haven't looked through all of them but I'm sure a dev has produced stats before about peak times etc... So between them, you may be able to get what you're after.

Comment: Another discussion of interest: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364490/what-are-some-statistics-around-the-number-of-users-who-have-a-positive-question