# Is it just me, or are there always a lot of new accounts with a name, a picture of them and little to no reputation?

Tags: discussion

I've been seeing a lot of accounts lately where someone is asking a question for (what appears to be) the first time on Stack Overflow. They've created their account, named it after them and have included a picture of themselves.

But I feel like I only see them once and they're gone - then there's another new wave of accounts like this.

Maybe my tinfoil hat's on too tight, but I suspect that some users are maybe afraid they're asking too many questions, so they create these catfish accounts to keep answers coming in without ever appearing to be super needy.

Has anyone else noticed this?

Comment: Yes, some of us noticed....

Comment: @rene Do you suspect these accounts are illegitimate?

Comment: Beyond curiosity what do you want to discuss?

Comment: @rene The legitimacy. And where these accounts are coming from/who's creating them and why?

Comment: Creating accounts is not forbidden nor is posting only once. So that by itself is completely legal.

Comment: @rene Right - but it looks like someone (and others) are under the impression that they'd rather create a fake account to ask more questions than continue to ask from one.

Comment: @dwirony Which they're allowed to do, as long as they don't do anything with the multiple accounts that they couldn't do with a single account

Comment: Sure, once sock-puppetry is detected the accounts are suspended if not removed

Comment: @rene Good to know - I feel like it's been rampant lately.

Comment: i mean, they could just be real people who don't have a lot of things to ask.

Comment: The photo may simply be because they've registered on other sites that share Gravatars (or equivalent), and as one-time newbie poster, they don't know how or don't care to change it. (Leaving aside that labeling "but they included a picture! Of *themselves*!" as 'suspicious activity' definitely is a case of too much tin foil.)

Comment: Well I don't like the pics.  They always seem to portray people who look better than I do:(

Comment: @Martin There is an easy solution to that: just look better!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very likely that the accounts are legitimate. In fact, I'm pretty sure the names and profile photos are also legit and come from an associated social media account:

> We now encourage users to set a name and picture during signup. If you sign up with Google or Facebook, we pull them in and let you edit them before you create an account.
>   <sub>[New! Smarter profile creation and syncing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239619/323179)</sub>

You can tell if a photo is from one of these sites by looking at its URL.

As Makoto says, most users only ask a single question and never come back, so it's extremely common to see new accounts.

Comment: Boom, this makes so much sense! I didn't know there was a way for people to instant create their profiles from another platform - I was wondering why these users were going through all the trouble to add pictures and information, etc. Now I understand. Sorry to Makoto but this is the answer I needed.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to loosen up the tinfoil hat, since [a large amount of accounts only ever ask *one* question to begin with.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364734/1079354)  It's definitely not a *problem* if that's the angle you were thinking about.